# Word macros are slow

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new to word Macros.

I have a task of highlighting all the bolds, italics, superscripts, subscripts. I have already written the code for it which works as expected but it is too slow even for a 50-page document can this code be improved?

**The Code**

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ch In ActiveDocument.Characters
    If ch.Font.Superscript = True Or ch.Font.Subscript = True Or ch.Font.Bold = True Or ch.Font.Italic = True Or ch.Font.Name = "Consolas" Or ch.Font.Name = "Courier New" Then
        ch.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Please let me know if this can be improved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There really is no need to loop through the document one character at a time. You should also learn to make more productive use of the tools already available via the GUI. In a long document, a few manual Find/Replace operations might even be faster than your macro! Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Font.Superscript = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Font.Subscript = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .ClearFormatting
    .Font.Name = "Consolas"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Font.Name = "Courier New"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```